# Android httppost setEntity

Tags: android

Не могу найти решение данной проблемы.

```
 Map<String, Object> socials = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    Map<String, Object> extra_data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                extra_data.put("expired", 0);
                data.put("extra_data", extra_data);
                profile.put("city" , SITY);
                profile.put("name" , USER_NAME);
                profile.put("sex" , SEX);
                profile.put("totalFriens" , COUNT_FRIENDS);
                data.put("profile", profile);
                data.put("provider", PROVIDER);
                data.put("token", TOKEN);
                data.put("uid", UID);
                JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
                json1.put("socials", data);


                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json1.toString());
                Log.e("DATA", json1.toString());
                httppost.setEntity(se);

итог:
    {"socials": {uid = 312321 ….}} - так должно быть

    {"socials":"{uid = 33333 …}"} - у меня так
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно сначала из мапы создать Json объект а потом уже добавлять в исходный

```
JSONObject socials = new JSONObject(data);
json1.put("socials", socials);
```

Так как в вашем случае `data` приводится к `String` и вы получаете то что получаете